# How to root Nokia 8?

Tags: rooting, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

I want to root my shiny and new [Nokia 8 64GB](https://www.nokia.com/en_ae/phones/nokia-8#details), running mostly pure Android 8.0.

This will later become part of the "[how to root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/102422)" series we have as a CW, following the wisdom of [this meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/790/102422).

Comment: Someone on XDA has rooted their Nokia 8 (proto), which has an unlocked bootloader though...: https://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-8/development/question-nokia-8-partitions-t3682617

Answer (score 1):

**Update April 23, 2018**: I just found it possible to unlock the bootloader for certain HMD Nokia phones, according to [this post on XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-6/how-to/guide-how-to-unlock-bootloader-qualcomm-t3769930).

**Do it at your own risk**.

---

<s>So far HMD Nokia is not root-able,</s> that's because HMD doesn't want to let the bootloader of Nokia 8 be unlockable. Without an unlocked bootloader, it's impossible to root a device (let alone system vulnerabilities - that's an *ancient* thing).

Don't attempt with *any* "This Root" or "That Root" tools or tutorials found online. They won't work for a rather new Android version (8.0). On the contrary they may harm the system in unknown ways.

[Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-8/help/how-root-t3668364) is a post on XDA Forum concerning about rooting Nokia 8. The result is the same: not possible so far.

I'll update this answer if things change.

Answer (score 0):

at this moment there is no way to root the nokia 8 because of the locked bootloader it has.