# remote: oem unlock is not allowed

Tags: rooting, adb, root-access, bootloader-lock, nokia-6

i did not find any solution on xda-developers, so i am posting this question here.
i am trying unlock bootloader on nokia6 when i give command:

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

or

```
sudo  fastboot flashing unlock
```

always i am getting error:

```
...
FAILED (remote: oem unlock is not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

**phone model: Nokia6(T1021)**

**android version: 8.0.0**

**usb debuging and oem unlocking is on**

Does Nokia not accept unlocking bootloader?

Comment: It seems, bootloader unlocking is not yet supported for Nokia phones.
Check this out : https://www.xda-developers.com/hmd-global-kernel-sources-bootloader-unlocking/

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware of, the Nokia Android phones by HMD Global **does not allow unlocking bootloader**. I have also stated the same in [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190015/205764).

So you're out of luck, at least for the time being.

Reference: [XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/hmd-global-kernel-sources-bootloader-unlocking/)

Answer (score -5):

So your question is Does Nokia not accept unlocking bootloader?

Technically it's not actually up to Nokia but more of the license that they're using to develop android firmware.

When developing an OS for Android you must follow the license terms of the AOSP ( Android Open Source Project ) this means that many elements of your firmware are strictly open source and any person should be granted the same access to the source code as they themselves have been granted by the license, many companies refuse to follow the GPL License in this way as well as many other license's, Technically you should be able to have access to the kernel source code due to such terms, however they'll refuse to give it up, Their has been many legal disputes about this that have forced companies to release the kernel source.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: Your question was "Does Nokia not accept unlocking bootloader?"

Comment: I also don't see how this is related to bootloader unlocking - the majority of the text is about the open-source nature of the OS and kernel, which the bootloader is not a part of.

Comment: To be able to unlock the bootloader of your device you'll need to have a modified kernel or modified boot.img to install over the old locked one, the only way to make this is by having access to the source code

Comment: No. Get some facts straight? To be able to install a custom/modified kernel you need an unlocked bootloader. Bootloader is a separate and proprietary part.

Comment: The **kernel** and the **bootloader** aren't one and the same, even if the name `boot.img` might have you think so. The kernel is a modified Linux kernel, which inherits the GPL license upstream is using, thus forcing whoever distributes its binaries to release its source; the bootloader is proprietary, hence closed source. Depending on the manufacturer and the carrier, said bootloader will be either unlocked, unlockable or locked down. The latter is what happens to OP's device.

Comment: Your edits also make no sense (and hence I have reverted them). This question is perfectly fine on this site. It is not the wrong place to ask. The license of the OS source has nothing to do with the ability - or lack thereof - to unlock the bootloader. That is why you are receiving downvotes, not because the question is somehow unclear. You may want to consider deleting this answer entirely.